# OpenCV Install for Pydev in Eclipse using Macports on OsX Mavericks

Tags: opencv, python-2.7, pydev, macports, python-idle

I used the following tutorial to install macports and opencv:
http://www.jeffreythompson.org/blog/2012/09/21/installing-opencv-for-python-on-mac-lion/

It works in that after typing "python" I can call "import cv" without errors.

My first question: how do I get this to work with IDLE. I think the issue is via the terminal I'm using Python 2.7.5. IDLE is using Python 2.7.3. If this is the problem, what is the easiest way to fix this.

My second question: how do I get opencv to work in eclipse with pydev? I can't really find much helpful information. I have installed opencv via macports. But I can't get Eclipse to recognize that opencv has been installed. "Import cv" command says no module named cv exists.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this problem today. Here are the steps I followed using macports

1. Install macports and xcode
2. Follow Sam Khans post listed here to install python, relink it in your terminal and then install OpenCV:
   http://samkhan13.wordpress.com/2012/06/18/using-opencv-with-python-on-your-mac-os-x/

NOTE: At this point you should be able to enter a terminal session and type "python" and then "import cv2" successfully.

1. Open eclipse and click on "eclipse" then "preferences" in the bar menu at the top of the program.
2. In the pop-up that appears click the arrow next to "pydev" to expand the menu then click "Interpreter - Python"
3. Press the "new" button on the right of the window
4. In the pop-up type in the name for this interpreter (I did python27 for my python2.7 version)
5. Next link the python executable for the desired version under the macports install tree "/opt/local/bin/pythonX.X" where X.X is your version (i.e. 2.7) and click ok.
6. A list of the available python libraries should populate. Select only those under the macport install tree (so we don't confuse our interpreter and cross list with another python build)
7. Finally click OK (which should automatically apply the changes).

The window will compile the interpreter and VOILA Python, Numpy and OpenCV working together through pydev in eclipse.